# Falcon REST api insert into table

Tags: python, sqlite, falconframework

I am making my first RESTful API using Falcon and SQlite3. 
I have the database with table called `students`. Each student has name and age properties. There is a several students in `students` table.

I want to insert a new student into my table using API I've created.
I am using `Insomnia` to make requests.

This is how my request looks like, its JSON object:

```
{
    "name":"JACK",
    "age":"213"
}
```

Leater I assigns the values from JSON to variables, and I am putting those names into my query.

My API:

```
import falcon
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////home/konrad/Desktop/source/falcon/database.db')

class testAPI(object):

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        connection = engine.connect()

        data = json.loads(req.stream.read())

        ageV = data['age']
        nameV = data['name']


        //This is how I am trying to insert data. 
        //connection.execute("INSERT INTO students (name, age) VALUES (nameV, ageV)")


        connection.close()

        print(data['name'])

        resp.body = data['name']
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

app = falcon.API()
xd = testAPI()
app.add_route('/', xd)
```

This way does not work. How should I insert the values into table?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. It was about python syntax.

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO students (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", (nameV, ageV))
```